# hidden files created in ubuntu visible in windows or MAC

Tags: file-permissions, ubuntu-16.04

I have a an external hardrive some directories and files are hidden using ubuntu (using . dot rename). I am wondering if these hidden files and directories will be visible if the HD is connected to a windows or MaC.If yes how can I hide or secure them.Thanks

Comment: `hide or secure them` – "Hidden files" and "data security" are two different concepts. If you want the latter then the former is not a good solution. Hidden files or directories are not displayed in some circumstances, that's all. You can [edit] the question and explain your goal (is it about security?) to avoid [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310), if any.

Comment: The hiding is just a display preference.  e.g., system files can be distracting if they clutter the display while you're not doing system maintenance.  So an option is provided to turn their display on and off.  That option can vary with each application that views it.

Comment: BTW, also consider the filesystem on the drive.  Some can be read natively by other OSes, some can only be read if you install a driver or utility that tells the OS how to do it.  So you may be reading the drive with different software, depending on the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a dot in front of a file or a folder on UNIX (therefore including MAC Os X) is just a convention that tells your OS "I don't want to see this file" you can still browse( -a option on ls) it and it does not change its permissions (read-write-execute) if you really don't want someone to see the content of a file, you should encrypt it. If you want to hide the filenames or the structure of your directory, you should put it in an encrypted container.

Basically, there is no such thing as an actual hidden file, only rules used by OS and software not to display some files

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your filesystem. But when you want to connect the harddrive to windows I think you use ntfs or fat. On both you can set the file/directory attributes to hidden.

MacOS also use the .-prefix for hidden files.

But to secure those files you should put them in an crypt container. As example with veracrypt or winrar or... .

Comment: Thanks Thomas.Just to understand 100% ( I am a newbie here..)If I use ubuntu and create a hidden dir with . dot). by default it that harddrive is connected to an MAC, these directories which I initially set as hidden will be seen?Can you tell me a bit more about crypt( I have large files in my directories -in terms of gigs. Thanks